# How to use KSS effectively with a CSS designed for dark mode?

Tags: html, css, background-color, darkmode, knyle-style-sheet

Suppose I intend to create a web page emplying dark mode. A very minimal page could look like this:

```css
:root {
  --fg-color: white;
  --bg-color: black;
}

body {
  color: var(--fg-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.simple {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2 class="simple">Hello world!</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now let's say I want to document it via KSS. I'd add these lines of comment before `.module`'s ruleset (leaving an empty line in between):

```css
/*
Simple

Markup:
<h2 class="simple">some text</h2>

Styleguide Simple.simple
*/

.simple {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

What disappoints me is that the documenation library takes the `color` but not the `background-color`, resulting in an unreadably white-on-white, as you can see below (the blue is a selection I made with the mouse):
[image]

Comment: Have you filed a bug with KSS's project page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official GitRepo for the KSS project was last updated in 2016](https://github.com/kneath/kss) with the majority of commits **made over 8 years ago** [in 2012-2013](https://github.com/kneath/kss/graphs/code-frequency).

2016, let alone 2013, was long before CSS Custom Properties were widely supported by browsers so it's no surprise that it's choking - though it's interesting that it seemed to recognize `color: var()` but not `background-color: var()`.

I'd call-it-quits and just document your CSS manually. The project seems dead. And [the project's author and maintainer seems more interested in funding innovative food production systems](https://warpspire.com/posts/resilience) than running an open-source project.

...or you could fork it and try to update it with the past 8 years of advances to CSS *and* stay on the maintenance treadmill.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer clearly explains the current situation: the project is dead.

For what concerns possible workarounds

I've found one that *kinda* works: setting `color` and `background-color` in `:root` rather than in `body` affects the KSS documentation page, thus resulting in accurate representation of the modules in the library. On the other hand, the KSS-specific stuff is negatively affected by this. But I still find the result better than having white on white as I described in the question.

Here's the result, where the back ground dark color applies to the whole page:
[image]

One that works slightly better consists in setting `color` and `background-color` both in `body` (not in `:root`) and `.kss-modifier__wrapper`:

[image]